# How to disable all the above checkbox options If someone click on None of the above checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have gone through some website which has the checkbox options like

Family : Wife Husband Son Daughter None.
If someone selected none option, then remaining all options are getting disabled

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and we can help from there.

Comment: If you have done any attempt on the code, you can show what you have done, and we can help you from there.

Comment: Need your efforts in terms of code, to get more understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code I hope it's helpful for you.

Thanks

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="father" class="group1">Father
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="mother" class="group1">mother
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="son & doughter" class="group1">son & doughter
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="none" id="none" class="group1">none

 $(function(){
 $("#none").on("click",function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $("input.group1").attr("disabled", true);
    }else{
        $("input.group1").attr("disabled", false);
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

{
  document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const t = e.target
    if (t.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'input' && t.type == 'checkbox' && t.dataset.trigger && t.dataset.trigger == 'none') {
      Array.from(t.form[t.name]).filter(el => el != t).forEach(el => el.disabled = t.checked)
    }
  })
}
```

```css
input:disabled + label {
  color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-form-relatives-wife" name="relatives">
  <label for="my-form-relatives-wife">Wife</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-form-relatives-husband" name="relatives">
  <label for="my-form-relatives-husband">Husband</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-form-relatives-son" name="relatives">
  <label for="my-form-relatives-son">Son</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-form-relatives-daughter" name="relatives">
  <label for="my-form-relatives-daughter">Daughter</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-form-relatives-none" name="relatives" data-trigger="none">
  <label for="my-form-relatives-none">None</label>
</form>
```

Here is a backward compatible version

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

{
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var t = e.target
    if (t.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'input' && t.type == 'checkbox' && t.dataset.trigger && t.dataset.trigger == 'none') {
    Array.prototype.filter.call(t.form[t.name], function(el) { return el != t }).forEach(function(el) { return el.disabled = t.checked})
    }
  })
}
```

```css
input:disabled + label {
  color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-form-relatives-wife" name="relatives">
  <label for="my-form-relatives-wife">Wife</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-form-relatives-husband" name="relatives">
  <label for="my-form-relatives-husband">Husband</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-form-relatives-son" name="relatives">
  <label for="my-form-relatives-son">Son</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-form-relatives-daughter" name="relatives">
  <label for="my-form-relatives-daughter">Daughter</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-form-relatives-none" name="relatives" data-trigger="none">
  <label for="my-form-relatives-none">None</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Please note: `Array.from` is not supported in Internet Explorer of any version: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility You will find a polyfill in this link